# Deleting a string from a text box is not working python

Tags: python, string, text, field

I am trying to delete a a word that is is a string from the text box.

But I get a following error:

```
TclError: bad text index "3"
```

Here is the code:

```
self.keys = "Bye"
def undo(self):
    I = self.Cont.search(self.keys,1.0,stopindex=END)
    self.Cont.delete(I,len(I))
```

Comment: Try to provide minimal working example (incl. imports). Also provide full error trace. Simplifying these things easily hides the cause.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky The problem is it wants a row and column I am just orviding one number by the len(I) It wants what row and column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using TkInter and a Text widget.

If so, then the `delete()` method takes two text index values, but you have given it one index and `len()` of the index string, which isn't meaningful.

I think you want something like:

```
def undo(self):
    countVar = IntVar()
    I = self.Cont.search(self.keys, 1.0, stopIndex=END, count=countVar)
    self.Cont.delete(I,'%s+%d chars' %(I, countVar.get()))
```

The count parameter tells search to store the match length into the IntVar object, which you can then retrieve with the .get() method.

The delete() method will then get an end index like: `"1.0 + 3 chars"`, which should identify a position just past the 'e'.

Comment: Actually it works great but if the user typed the same word it will delete the first word and not the last one which is what I want.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find the last occurrence of the word and delete that one?  You might try searching backwards from the last index by setting the `backwards=True` option.

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Ok, then you'd say something like: `search(self.keys, END, backwards=True, count=countVar)`

Comment: It works but if the user hits Enter ot go to the next line and types something then if they hit undo to do it I get a error saying: TclError: bad text index ""

Comment: You'll need to print out your index values and make sure they make sense.  I'd start by printing both the search return value and the countVar value.

Comment: i ahve figured out that the problem. If the user hits search and you type something and hit undo the white spaces in between the line and where they hit space then the next line is messing up the program. I ahve tryed somethings but they did not work and also it just prints 0 and no other number.